# Google autocomplete place search box not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Google autocomplete place search box shows "oops , something went wrong." .My code here`

```
routerApp.directive('googleplace', function(){
 return {
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, model){
          var options = {
                           types: [],
                           componentRestrictions: {}
                         };
 scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], options);
 google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function(e) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      model.$setViewValue(element.val());
      var countrycode = "na";
      scope.secondplacebox = scope.chosenPlace;

      for(var i = 0; i < scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components.length; i++)
      {   
        if(scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components[i].types[0] == 'country')
         {
           countrycode = scope.gPlace.getPlace().address_components[i].short_name;

         }
      }

      var latitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6);
      var longitude = scope.gPlace.getPlace().geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6);
      scope.Fn_SearchFood(latitude,longitude,scope.date,countrycode);       

               });
     });
    }
  };
});
```

and I am using

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=API_KEY"></script>
```

Please show me an example to give project url in the google api console.
Please help,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any problem with the code????

Comment: I am stuck with the error --"util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"